# Google Search results show one link but no description

Tags: google-search, meta-description

Search for this term in Google: [cop-groningen](http://www.google.nl/#q=cop-groningen) or click the link to get to the page without typing. It shows you a link at the top of the search results page: `www.cop-groningen.nl/`.

Below it I see neither a description (in black) nor a breadcrumb (in green). The preview is not working either (it says: no preview available). If you click the link, the site loads as expected.

This is a snippet from the website's homepage:

```
    < meta name="keywords" content="COP, groep, COPgroep, peuteropvang, slochteren, kidsfirst" />  
    < meta name="description" content="Stichting COP groep - Organisatie voor gesubsidieerde peuterspeelzalen en opvoedingsondersteuning in de stad Groningen" />
```

**EDIT:**

The website has been on air for ages, and has had a description before. I now also see in Google Analytics that no visitors were reported after 15 january 2012. There have been visitors, however.

Anyone get any idea why this is the case? I try to analyse with Wireshark but I'm not good for analysing packets. I just don't get it.

Comment: How recently was the meta title and description added to the site? Have you signed up for google webmaster tools and checked that it's indexing your site correctly?

Comment: See my edits above. I have no webmaster account. I will get one.

Comment: Data point: It looks like *none* of your pages' meta descriptions are being used, and a quick search suggests that Bing is doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently add/update your robots.txt? Often when it's just a link with no other info it's because the page has been blocked in robots.txt but discovered by Google through other links therefore the URL is indexed but none of the content on the URL is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that has the same question, please check if you have uploaded a wrong version of robots.txt.
Mine was

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: *
```

Better change it to (in case of a Joomla site)

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /administrator/
    Disallow: /cache/
    Disallow: /components/
    Disallow: /images/
    Disallow: /includes/
    Disallow: /installation/
    Disallow: /language/
    Disallow: /libraries/
    Disallow: /media/
    Disallow: /modules/
    Disallow: /plugins/
    Disallow: /templates/
    Disallow: /tmp/
    Disallow: /xmlrpc/
```

I'll be under a rock for the coming few days, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a real oddity, I have no solid idea why Google isn't indexing your site correctly, code's valid (there appear to be some line breaks inside the meta description but that shouldn't do any harm) - your robots.txt looks like this:-

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /xmlrpc/
```

Does the html or templates for any of the indexed pages reside in a directory other than the root, could one of these be preventing a full index and Google is just listing the base url?

Comment: That's because i discovered that robots.txt was on disallow. I changed it, but could not answer my own question. Thanks for being so thourough.

Comment: @KimAlders no worries, happens to all of us!